# Why does my ceiling fan turn off when I turn on the lights?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I just installed a new ceiling fan in my kids room earlier today.  There are two switches on the wall.  I started the day with a dimmer switch and a regular switch.  Once everything was installed I turned the power back on and the fan worked, but as soon as I turned on the light (on the dimmer switch) the fan would start making a humming noise and would start slowing down.

I couldn't get it to work right so I thought maybe the dimmer switch was the issue.  I had a regular switch laying around so I swapped it out for the dimmer so now I have two regular single pole switches.  I turn on the fan at the switch, works like a charm.  I then turn on the light (at the newly installed regular switch) and the light turns on BUT the fan turns off!  No humming any more from the motor, but it just turns off.  As soon as I turn the light back off the fan turns back on.

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

I had that same problem I fix the problem bye checking between the fan and the light there wire connection connected wrong just disconnect the 2 wires coming from the fan to the light switch them around and your problem should go away. You have one common and one power switched. Good luck.